# Alternatives for "It's been long since we met"

Tags: phrases, alternatives

Let's assume person A and B have been apart for decades and they finally meet now.

Then A might say "It has been long since we met." and this is correct.

But I'm wondering, as alternatives, if following sentences are okay and have no error in grammar.

> 1. It has been long without you.
> 2. It has been long to see you again.
> 3. It has been long not seeing you.

Please give me your answer. :)

Comment: I'd use the [idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/long+time+no+see) *Long time no see*.

Comment: Your examples are incomplete, the tem is "***a long time***" not just "***long***"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example sentences aren't correct, here are revisions.

> It has been *a long time* since we met.

OK.

> It has been *a long time* without you.

OK

> It has been *a long time* to see you again.

No. It could be: "It has been a long time. I am happy to see you again." or "I've waited a long time to see you again."

> It has been *a long time* not seeing you.

OK, although possibly better as: "It has been a long time that we haven't seen each other."